# How do you avoid data loss when peer resets TCP connection in winsock 2?

Tags: tcp, router, upnp, winsock2

I am writing a UPnP client and one of my test routers always "slams" the connection shut, instead of doing a graceful shutdown-send after it has sent a response. This results in my recv calls not getting the data.

I know the data is there because I can see it in a packet sniffer.

If my code races ahead fast enough to recv the data before the connection reset, then I get the data. In many cases, the peer resets the connection before I can recv it, resulting in no data copied to my receive buffer, and a WSAECONNRESET error from recv.

Any ideas how to fix my end to tolerate badly written UPnP implementation in netgear router?

I tried using WSAEventSelect and making reads asynchronous, which seemed to help but it doesn't always work.

```
// Object that manages reliably sending and receiving, even if the
// peer does stupid things like slamming connection shut at EOF
class Transceiver
{
    SOCKET sock;
    AutoWSACloseEvent syncEvent;

    // Buffer pool
    template<size_t bufferSize>
    struct Buffer
        : public SLIST_ENTRY
        , public AutoPool<Buffer<bufferSize>, false>
    {
        char data[bufferSize];

        size_t size() const
        {
            return bufferSize;
        }
    };

public:
    Transceiver() : sock(INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
    }
    int Init(SOCKET sock);
    int SendAll(const std::string &data);
    int ReceiveAll(std::string &data);
};



int UpnpNat::Transceiver::Init(SOCKET sock)
{
    int err;

    this->sock = sock;
    syncEvent = WSACreateEvent();
    if (!syncEvent)
        return ErrorHook(WSAGetLastError());
    err = WSAEventSelect(sock, syncEvent, FD_READ | FD_CLOSE);
    if (err == SOCKET_ERROR)
        return ErrorHook(WSAGetLastError());

    return NO_ERROR;
}

int UpnpNat::Transceiver::SendAll(const std::string &request)
{
    for (int ofs = 0; ofs < (int)request.length(); )
    {
        auto xferSize = send(sock, &request[ofs], (int)request.length() - ofs, 0);
        if (xferSize == SOCKET_ERROR)
            return ErrorHook(WSAGetLastError());
        ofs += xferSize;
    }

    return NO_ERROR;
}

int UpnpNat::Transceiver::ReceiveAll(std::string &response)
{
    int err = NO_ERROR;
    int xferSize;

    auto responseBuf = MakeAutoDelete(new Buffer<16384>());
    if (!responseBuf)
        return ErrorHook(ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY);

    bool needRecvWait = false;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (needRecvWait)
        {
            needRecvWait = false;
            if (WSAWaitForMultipleEvents(1, syncEvent.Storage(),
                    FALSE, 30000, FALSE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            {
                err = WSAETIMEDOUT;
                return ErrorHook(err);
            }

            WSANETWORKEVENTS wsane;
            ZeroInit(&wsane);
            err = WSAEnumNetworkEvents(sock, syncEvent, &wsane);
            if (err == SOCKET_ERROR)
                return ErrorHook(WSAGetLastError());

            if (wsane.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE)
            {
                err = wsane.iErrorCode[FD_CLOSE_BIT];
                break;
            }

            if ((wsane.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ) == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (wsane.iErrorCode[FD_READ_BIT] != NO_ERROR)
                return ErrorHook(wsane.iErrorCode[FD_READ_BIT]);
        }

        xferSize = recv(sock, responseBuf->data, (int)responseBuf->size(), 
                MSG_PARTIAL);
        if (xferSize == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            err = WSAGetLastError();
            if (err == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                needRecvWait = true;
                continue;
            }
            // Workaround for crap routers that slam connection shut at EOF
            if (err == WSAECONNRESET && response.length() > 0)
                return NO_ERROR;

            return ErrorHook(WSAGetLastError());
        }
        if (xferSize <= 0)
            break;

        response.append(responseBuf->data, 0, (std::string::size_type)xferSize);
    }

    return ErrorHook(err);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by 'slams' you mean 'sends an RST', no there is nothing you can do. The TCP stack is obliged to abort the connection and discard all pending data if an RST is received.

Comment: @doug65536 That's a curious way of putting it. The statement was always correct.